# Find the extremals of $I[y]=\int_0^1(y')^2 \mathrm dt+\{y(1)\}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Could anyone help me find the extremals of 
$$I[y]=\int_0^1(y')^2 \mathrm dx+\{y(1)\}^2$$ subject to $y(0)=1$

Most crucially I can't work out how to find the boundary $x=1$. I'm trying to go back to first principles and letting $y \rightarrow y+\alpha \eta$. Here the normal step would be to differentiate and set $\alpha=0$ and hence derive the Euler-Lagrange equation.

If anyone can explain to me how to deal with this case i'd be very grateful!

Comment: You can write $[y(1)]^2=[y(x)^2]_0^1-1=\int_0^1\frac 12yy'dx -1$ and use what you know.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: That is excellent! So group together and solve the Euler-Lagrange equation. How does this help us find the boundary condition though?

Comment: You have to put $y(1)=a$ and discuss the extremals in function of this parameter.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Ok, I apologize if I don't understand this topic, as it's all be self taught this evening (problem sheet due in before the first lecture you see)
So I solved the Euler-Lagrange equation to get 
$y''=0 \Rightarrow y=ax+1$
is this the correct approach? So the extremals is a family of lines?

Comment: It's the correct approach. Can you show your computations which led you to Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I said
$I[y]=\int_0^1(y')^2 \mathrm dx+\{y(1)\}^2=I[y]=\int_0^1((y')^2+ \frac 12yy'-1)\mathrm dx$
Letting $F(x,y,y')=(y')^2+ \frac 12yy'-1$ I then apply the method found on page $6$ of this document.
http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2011/986/3/CalcVar.pdf
Which leads to the Euler-Lagrange equation, or have I missed a condition or made some fundemental error somewhere...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2235/discussion-between-davide-giraudo-and-lhs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disregard this answer if the question is a homework problem in variational calculus.)

It is obvious that $I(y)$ can be made arbitrarily large, so we only have to look for the minimum. The situation here is so simple that we can do with Schwarz' inequality. Put $y(1)=:y_1$. Then
$$(y_1-1)^2=\Bigl(\int_0^1 1\cdot y'(x)\ dx\Bigr)^2\leq \int_0^1 1^2\ dx\cdot \int_0^1 y'^2(x)\ dx$$
with equality iff $y'(x)$ is constant. It follows that
$$I(y):=\int_0^1 y'^2(x)\ dx + y_1^2\geq 2y_1^2-2y_1+1=2\Bigl(y_1-{1\over2}\Bigr)^2 +{1\over2}\ .$$
Therefore $I(y)\geq{1\over2}$, and the minimum is attained for the function $y(x):=1-{x\over2}$.

Comment: This is a very different approach to the one I've been considering, thank you for your input

Comment: @LHS you should accept this answer instead of mine, since what I did is wrong. (then I will be allowed to delete it)

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Ah ok, I see what's happened now. Thanks so much anyway!!